# SQLite saving string in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, nsstring

Hello I'm trying to save string into `SQLite` database, but nothing happens. I have a string:

> "tret44404%40ukr.net%3A100001740940428%3A06Kz8p1Xbk0PzpH%2F%3A0%3Av_1%2Cajax_1%2Cwidth_320%2Cpxr_1%2Cgps_1%3A1307716802"

I'm trying to save it to database but it saving string as:

> "tret44404
>   80792kr.net-0X1.FD428P+01000017409404280X1.B2C260000001P-100906Kz8p1Xbk0PzpH0.0000000X1.149242P-104700X1.400000018P-1040v_1灠ajax_1Ῐwidth_320"

A method how I save string:

```
- (void) addCookie {


    if(addStmt == nil) {
        const char *sql = "insert into FaceBookCookies(userId, created, domain, Expires, HttpOnly, Name, Path, Value) Values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
    sqlite3_bind_int(addStmt, 1, userID);
    sqlite3_bind_int(addStmt, 2, created);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 3, [domain UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
    sqlite3_bind_double(addStmt, 4, [Expires timeIntervalSince1970]);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 5, [HttpOnly UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 6, [Name UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 7, [Path UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_STATIC);

    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 8, [Value UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_STATIC); //here is a String...

    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    else
        //SQLite provides a method to get the last primary key inserted by using sqlite3_last_insert_rowid
        userID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);

    //Reset the add statement.
    sqlite3_reset(addStmt);
}
```

Please help how to fix it...

Comment: Did you even look at the preview before submitting the question? how about formatting it better so we can see what's going on? See the formatting help here : http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: dean was right you can use the formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must probably remove the percent escapes before saving. Do it like this,

```
sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 8, [[Value stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
```

Comment: thanks, but now it's returning string: tret44404                                   68667kr.net0X0P+01000017409404280X1.B269C04C123DP-100906Kz8p1Xbk0PzpH0.0000000X1.D849400016C8CP-102100X1.D84FDBFFFD4F8P-1021v_1靰ajax_1වwidth_320츰pxr_1鑰gps_10X1.9000004C1947P+51307716802

Comment: Ok, I save string.. And Now I have a SQLite bug, may be =)
when I save string and displaying it I have: tret44404 68667kr.net0X0P+01000017409404280X1.B269C04C123DP-100906Kz8p1Xbk0PzpH0.0000000X1.D849400016C8CP-102100X1.D84FDBFFFD4F8P-1021v_1靰ajax_1වwidth_320츰pxr_1鑰gps_10X1.9000004C1947P+51307716802

But when I restarting program I have a NORMAL string with "@" it's replacing "%40".
What can it be??

Comment: How are you getting the value back?